# HippoMocks - mocking a function that returns a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, mocking, hippomocks

I am currently not succeding in mocking an interface that returns a unique_ptr. For example, given

```
struct IFoo {     
    virtual std::unique_ptr<IFoo> foo = 0;
};


int main()
{
    MockRepository mocks;
    auto foo = mocks.Mock<IFoo>();
    mocks.OnCall( foo, IFoo::foo )
         .Return( std::unique_ptr<IFoo>() );
}
```

This fails to compile because the `Return` implementation makes a copy of the unique_ptr

```
Call &Return(Y obj) { retVal = new ReturnValueWrapper<Y>(obj); return *this; }
```

and the expectation attempts to return the unique_ptr

```
template <typename Z>
Z MockRepository::DoExpectation(base_mock *mock, std::pair<int, int> funcno, const base_tuple &tuple)
{
    ...
    return ((ReturnValueWrapper<Z> *)call->retVal)->rv;
}
```

I've tried `Do`, as suggested [for a similar problem with returned references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772970/hippomocks-mocking-return-values-by-ref).

I've also tried writing my own `ValueWrapper<T>` that generates a unique_ptr, but somewhere the value always gets copied. Right now I've run out of ideas.

Comment: It seems HippoMocks is not ready for C++11's move-only types yet. Maybe you could write a specialization for `ReturnValueWrapper<std::unique_ptr<IFoo>>` that does *not* copy internally?

Comment: Have you tried hippomocks later versions, that have a C++0x version?

Comment: @Arne I had more or less tried something like that. Apparently I did something wrong initially. After giving in another go I found a solution that worked. I'll be adding it to the [github repository](https://github.com/dascandy/hippomocks) later.

Comment: @Thomas I ran into this exact problem yesterday. Would love to see your changes on Github!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to the problem is to create a derived interface with an additional method that returns the return value as a temporary

```
template <class T>
class TypedReturnValueHolder : public ReturnValueHolder {
public:
    virtual T rv() = 0;
};
```

and them modifying the original `ReturnValueHolder`

```
template <class T>
class ReturnValueWrapper : public ReturnValueHolder {
public:
typename no_cref<T>::type rv;
ReturnValueWrapper(T rv) : rv(rv) {}
};
```

to inherit from and implement the derived interface.

```
template <class T>
class ReturnValueWrapper : public TypedReturnValueHolder<T> {
    typename no_cref<T>::type prv;
public:
    ReturnValueWrapper(T rv) : prv(rv) {}
    virtual T rv() { return prv; };
};
```

Once that has been done, the return from `DoExpectation` can be written as

```
        if (call->retVal)
            return ((TypedReturnValueHolder<Z> *)call->retVal)->rv();
```

The example from the question when rewritten to use `Do`

```
mocks.OnCall( foo, IFoo::foo )
     .Do( [](){ return std::unique_ptr<IFoo>(); } );
```

then compiles and runs as expected.